# SSIS DT_TEXT (CodePage 1254) to NVARCHAR conversation

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, ssis

I am trying to get data from Google Bigquery to ms sql server via SSIS. In data source data type is DT_Text and during etl process, I lost some special characters like İ,Ü,ü etc. Target data type is varchar. I cannot change DT_Text to nvarchar via data type conversation, it doesn't work. How can I get data from Bigquery to SSIS without losing the characters?

Many Thanks!

Collation of target database is:`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

**Ps**
When I try to insert data like this;
`insert into target table(target column) values (N'İİİ')` there is no problem, I can see İİİ in the table. However when I insert data like this :`insert into target table(target column) values ('İİİ')`
I see III in the target table.

Comment: Can you do a cast of the DT_TEXT to DT_NTEXT? Then it should be able to write to an NVARCHAR table column.

Comment: As to the difference between `N'İİİ'` and `'İİİ'`... the `İ` character (U+0130) does not exist in [the Windows-1252 codepage](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/charsets/windows-1252) used by the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1` collations. If you want to use `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` columns and data types then you'll need to use one of the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254` collations which use [the Windows-1254 code page](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/charsets/windows-1254) instead.

Comment: why not change the column to nvarchar, if it's storing "special" characters

Comment: How are you getting data from BigQuery because in my naïve thinking, the fact that your source is interpreting the data type as DT_TEXT and not  DT_NTEXT will the root of your data loss.